# Keep the same sizes with different zooms

Tags: css, mobile

I haven't found anything on the forum, this question may be stupid but I'm a newbie. I'm trying to do a "button" that when I click on it, something happens. But this isn't the problem. I don't know how to keep the button in the center of the page, with any zoom, on pc and on mobile. I thought to use an image, but I want to ask anyway how to do that if I need it.

- The code is simple, but there are two problems I don't know how to
  fix: When I zoom in or out, the box remains the same, but the font
  size changes. I don't know how to make it static;
- On mobile, everything is wrong placed, I seriously don't know what to do

```css
   #div{
    height:10%;
    width:50%;
    border:0.01em solid black;
    background-color:lightblue;
    border-radius:500em;
    position:absolute;
    left:25%;
    top:45%;
   }

   #p{
    text-align:center;
    margin:0px;
    position:relative;
    height:50%;
    top:25%;
                /*not sure if this is how to center the text*/
      
    font-size:1em; /*not sure*/
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Bottone inutile</title>
  <script>
          /*...*/
  </script>
  <style>
          /*...*/
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="div" onclick="something()">
   <p id="p">text</p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The zoom button on browsers is meant to change the layout of the page. If the font size does not increase, the zoom is irrelevant isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but if I make a static box, the text continues to go outside the div

Comment: Like that?  https://jsfiddle.net/oqxpz4dq/

Comment: Yes but in part. The text now remains in the center, but it keeps to change the size when I zoom in or out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Pure CSS method**

I am not sure if this will do the trick for you but I develope online designers that have to keep everything responsive and in place.  Things like images are usually no problem at all as I set a container at 100% and all layers above it get width and height in % as to scale perfectly.

Text on the other hand is not as easy but can be done fairly easily.

What I do is instead of using px, pt, em or rem is simply use vw.

> vw : hundredths of the viewport width. vh : hundredths of the viewport
>   height. vmin : hundredths of whichever is smaller, the viewport width
>   or height. vmax : hundredths of whichever is larger, the viewport
>   width or height.

This basically makes it responsive and each 1vw is 1% of the viewport width. Depending on needs you may need to create some @media code for different break points.

**Optional JS method**.(if applicable)
A great plugin to resize all text : http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/

**Note:** I am not affiliated with simplefocus.